# Pytest-xdist 3.40 and higher not honoring --exitfirst

Tags: pytest-xdist

I just updated my libraries and pytest is no longer exiting on the first failed test as it used to.

The following pytest-related packages were updated (version updated included):

- pytest (7.4.3)
- pytest-asyncio (0.23.2)
- pytest-rerunfailures (13.0)
- pytest-xdist (3.5.0)

The only way I have been able to fix the issue is to pin xidst to 3.3.1

I have tried downgrading some libraries in different combinations with the latest version of xidst installed(3.5.0). Although I didn't try every possible combination of libraries, it seems that the only way to fix the issue is to pin xdist.

Python version 3.11.6.

The changelog of xdist 3.4.0 & 3.5.0 doesn't look like it contains changes that would cause this issue. Anyone experience this and have a workaround?

Comment: it's probably better to just file a github issue in this sort of scenario. i filed https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/1034.

Comment: @burnettk thank you for doing that, I should have thought to do the same